# Store compiled model in Keras?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I'd like to use a Keras model in production but don't want to have to re-compile the model everytime I need to run it. Should I just pickle it, etc.?

Comment: Theano or TensorFlow back end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is predict (and not train in production) it is not necessary to compile the model.

Source: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2621

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `pickle` isn't supported by Keras at the moment. You can either:

- Use the built-in 'keras.models.load_model' and 'keras.models.save_model' to store the model and the trained weights to a hdf5 file.
- Use a patchy trick to make Keras models "picklable". Useful if you have an object that references a model. I did it once and put a post in my blog - http://zachmoshe.com/2017/04/03/pickling-keras-models.html